# Which is the best way to get deployed server version?

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I usually track my server version with the version field of my `package.json`.

Sometimes it is really useful to have a `/version` route to rapidly inspect the deployed version. I am thinking about doing this:

```
app.get('/version', (req, res) => {
    let pack = require('../package.json');
    res.send(pack.version);
});
```

Is there a better way (most clean, cross-platform, simplest, logical)?

Comment: i think that's the right way to do as well.

Comment: I would say it depends on the usecase for the information, so what do you wish to use the information for?

Comment: @TuanAnhTran , The best answer is way cleaner.

Comment: @R.Gulbrandsen , to get the package version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `env` params in your script if launched using : `'npm start'`

```
res.send({version:process.env.npm_package_version})
```

Comment: I prefer this: 
    `app.get('/version', (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).send(process.env.npm_package_version);
    });` . Thanks alot.